# GoogleSheet Formula For Matching Company URLs

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have a list with two columns. Each column has a company URL. Unfortunately, each column has differences (I.e. unroll.me vs. http://Unroll.me/app).

I need a formula that will match column A to B and in column, C  give me a "YES" or a "NO".

My master list has 800.

Comment: Here is my Google Sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aQPmMoMvJhYyOHpkYyMh5EaBhAERMjilZRYVS64Xkbo/edit#gid=0

A formula or a fuzzy look-up script would be great.

Comment: Why is the first one a match?

Comment: Because the names in the url match and bring you to the same company website, not necessarily the same page, but the same company website. 

If I could find a way to match the names after the www., HTTP., https://. and before the .com that would be ideal. 

www.newelevation.com will bring you to the same page as https://newelevationinc.com

Comment: The only way you can find that out is if you navigate to those pages or compare web responses. There's no way to tell this just by looking at two different hostnames, however similar they might be.

Comment: I know in MS EXCEL you can use Fuzzy Lookup add-in to view a %match rate. At this time I am only working with google sheets though. I appreciate you looking In to it. I will continue to search for a solution.

Comment: Well, yes, you can compare urls for similarity (easiest would be with a script), but there's no way to tell that two hosts lead to the same place without interacting with the web in some way. Eg, if I made a malicious site and called it neweievation dot com, the host names would be very similar, but the websites would be very different.